# readimagefile() not working as expected (C++)

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm trying to create sprites from a picture and when I use `readimagefile()` it just displays a black window. I tried the same code on an other file with different `x` and `y` and it was working fine. I checked, and the files are in the correct directories and the `x` and `y` sized match. Here are the codes

```
int gd = DETECT;
int gm;

initwindow(1000, 600, "Window", 20, 20, 0, 1);
readimagefile("load.jpg", 0, 0, 8, 8);
getch();
```

^This one is working

```
int gd = DETECT;
int gm;

initwindow(1000, 600, "Window", 20, 20, 0, 1);
readimagefile("sprites.jpg", 0, 0, 200, 100);
getch();
```

^This one isn't

(graphics, conio, stdlib, stdio are included)

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: seems like it just didn't like the .jpg format, even though i have imagemagick. Just use bmp.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the problem, it's the bit depth color
it seems `readimagefile()` function can only read images with 24-bit depth
so you have to convert your image to that specific bit depth.